# How to disable discrete graphics card and use only integrated graphics MacBook Pro Early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, gpu

I have a MacBook Pro Early 2011 and the GPU has died. I want to switch to Integrated
Graphics only until I get my Logic Board replaced.

I've tried:

- gfxcardstatus and I get this:

  [image]
- There is no External Display connected btw and I've never used one.
- I moved /System/Library/Extensions/AMD* -> ~/DisabledExtensions/
- I've tried Single User Mode and did the same thing as above.

I really don't know what else to do. I want to know if there is a way
to login to EFI/BIOS and disable it or anyway whatever it takes to just kill that
annoying AMD that is making my screen blue and twitchy.

Comment: is the monitor choice in system preferences not working for you

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by that...I don't
have another monitor attached it's just the laptop monitor
that's it

Comment: maybe this question will be helpful for you? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103966/opengl-acceleration-with-intel-hd-3000/

Comment: Thanks Guido I tried moving those files already only thing I didn't move was AppleIntelHD3000Graphics.kext and I just moved it but the problem still persists blue highlighted screen and gfxcardstatus detects an external monitor where there isn't one...

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/836910/disable-discrete-graphics-card-on-macbook-pro-early-2011 , but removing drivers, you only make MacOS to use a fallback mode, you do not force it to use the integrated gfx. Unfortunetely.

Comment: bit of an update, April 2017.  First, the MBP repair extension seems to be over (it was supposed to run to Dec 31, 2016).  Second, some of the fixes involved moving files from the `/System/Library/Extensions`.  I could do this just fine from **Single-user Mode**, but, in MacOS Sierra, those files are "protected" by SIP.  `csrutil disable` would turn off SIP, but disabling SIP that way can only be done in **Recovery Mode**. Which is... graphical and fails due to my GPU issue.  Catch 22 :-(

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that using certain EFI variable. I answered [this other question][1] with the full procedure to permanently disable discrete graphics card on startup.


  [1]: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285896/94184

Comment: Easier and Mac-only procedure to be found here now: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/251859

Comment: I can vouch for [Fernando Nieto's solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805)  which seems to be derived from Luis Puerto's post [Disconnecting the dGPU in a late 2011 MacBook Pro](https://luispuerto.net/blog/2017/12/11/disconnecting-the-dgpu-in-a-late-2011-macbook-pro-third-way/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally!! ( in 2015...? )
MacBook Pro Repair Extension Program for Video Issues

http://www.apple.com/ca/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

I hope this helps everyone.

Comment: Mac models known to be affected by this issue but **older than 3 years** are **not** covered by the Repair Extension Program. Can someone confirm or deny this?

Comment: @Paolo "The program covers affected MacBook Pro models until **February 27, 2016** or three years from its original date of sale, **whichever provides longer coverage for you**."

Comment: My 15" MBP early 2011's motherboard was replaced twice by Apple's Authorised Service Provider - issue still pertains. First replacement lasted about 10 reboots or couple of hours, second - allowed me to use it for several weeks with rare glitches or reboots. Then it died too. I'm tired of sending mac back and forth to another city. Better try to turn discrete graphics OFF or sell it as-is to whoever will buy it. So - that program is not a silver bullet, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah my MacBook Pro mid 2010 model has this problem but is not covered by this program :(

Comment: I bought my late 2011 17" MacBook Pro in Sept 2012. I just got it back with a replaced logic board under this program. I've barely used it since getting it back, but when I took it in, the video was failed as soon as the machine was powered-on, so it seems like a massive improvement. I'm very impressed with their customer-service, totally reasonable not to do anything for free years after the warranty expired. Excellent work Apple.

Comment: My Mid 2010 MacBook Pro isn't covered by that. :(

Comment: In the print at the bottom of the page, it says "The program covers affected MacBook Pro models until December 31, 2016 OR four years from its original date of sale, whichever provides longer coverage for you."  I am going to call them tomorrow!

Comment: They are going to fix it under the program, simply because I fall within the purchase date and have the symptoms.  Regardless of serial.

Comment: looks like it is over now.  I entered my serial # and got a big "out of coverage", from the UK site (I live in Canada).  The small print there say till Dec 31, 2016.

Comment: It is over indeed for 2011 models, so I don't think this should be the accepted answer anymore..

Comment: This solution was completely invalidated now by the march of time. After expiration of Apple's grace you need to go here: apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/251859

Comment: Hello future people!  This problem is caused by a single bad capacitor, Apple used one that's too small so it goes bad eventually.  You can replace it yourself with a soldering iron and $8 replacement, following one of these videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzcgT_fiVTA https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKBzrxSGwlo  To buy a new (better) capacitor: https://store.rossmanngroup.com/d3-c7771-c9560-1-piece.html

Comment: I did turn in a couple of 2011 MBP for graphic card/motherboard replacement successfully. Now that the program is not running any more I can vouch for [Fernando Nieto's solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805)  which seems to be derived from Luis Puerto's post [Disconnecting the dGPU in a late 2011 MacBook Pro](https://luispuerto.net/blog/2017/12/11/disconnecting-the-dgpu-in-a-late-2011-macbook-pro-third-way/). No Linux, no hardware mods, reversible, powers down Radeon GPU.

Answer (score 10):

you definitely should try this one:
http://www.asyncro.com/2014/03/24/macbook-pro-discreate-graphics-card-issue-fix-updated/
(that is still on [archive.org: Macbook Pro Discreate Graphics Card Issue Fix Updated](https://web.archive.org/web/20141216212441/http://www.asyncro.com/2014/03/24/macbook-pro-discreate-graphics-card-issue-fix-updated/))

I’m writing this reply from my until-now broken MacBook Pro 2011 dammed GPU piece of technology.

You'll get away working without the AMD GPU, which vs. having a dead USD$2k… paperweight isn't really a bad deal.

**Additional Solution**:

I found that doing the above will let you login, but Mac OS would still try to use the discrete graphics card without the driver.  The result is that even though you can login, the graphics will be so slow that the machine is mostly unusable.

The second answer (the one that uses ArchLinux ISO to change the EFI variable) on this link solved my problem:

[MacBook Pro: How to disable discrete GPU permanently from EFI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/macbook-pro-how-to-disable-discrete-gpu-permanently-from-efi)

My Mac OS now boots up default to integrated graphics mode.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. To prevent link rot, please summarize the relevant information from the link in your answer.

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: It also worked perfectly for me. The interesting and very great to share with you that my discrete graphics card is running perfectly now. I have just followed the way of keep the machine running with the blue screen of death until the machine turned off automatically. Then I just restarted the machine and now it's running okay. I hope it will keep going forever...

Comment: @gypsicoder after almost a year - still works?

Comment: Additional solution worked great for me.

Comment: After years using gfxCardStatus under El Capitan and High Sierra, I had to revisit disabling the Radeon 6570 in my MBP 2011 17" to upgrade to Mojave. I can vouch for [Fernando Nieto's solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267581/gpu-problem-boot-hangs-on-grey-screen/295805#295805)  which seems to be derived from Luis Puerto's post [Disconnecting the dGPU in a late 2011 MacBook Pro](https://luispuerto.net/blog/2017/12/11/disconnecting-the-dgpu-in-a-late-2011-macbook-pro-third-way/). Works perfectly, no headaches, reversible, no hardware mods.

Answer (score 5):

You did right so far. But you have to move all ATI files from that folder as well. It will work after that, but the graphic will be slow.

Make sure to boot in verbose mode (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> at startup).

```
mount -uw /  (to be able to move System files)
mv /System/Library/Extensions/ATI* /System/Library/DisabledExtensions/
```

Note that the Folder `DisabledExtensions` needs to exist already.

Addendum: It’s important to put that Intel3000.....kext file back! You will need that one!

Comment: After doing this, it boots again, but only in Safe Mode. When booting without it, it gets stuck with mouse pointer on the "login screen background" (but no other elements, so no way to log in). Do you have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all I have used the linked procedure - http://www.asyncro.com/2014/03/24/macbook-pro-discreate-graphics-card-issue-fix-updated/
Although while rebuilding the drivers cache it has given me down the line "segmentation fault" but when it booted:

I have noticed in Energy Saver "Automatic switching check box was removed now".Also My external video 6770m card is completely disabled as to test I have tried the game which previously was always going to 2nd gpu but now only using integrated GPU.

Also before doing all this I have updated to Yosemite.

Benefit of upgrade was : 
Now when the system panics- Apple has made some changes in 6770m gpu drivers that is forcing the CPU to reinitialize or reboot the GPU - so now when system reboots it comes back safely. So no more recovery mode boot or single user or pram resets or SMC. It was coming back everytime.

But the disadvantage was everytime it was switching gpu during normal use it was crashing the laptop and rebooting. I had previously noticed the Webex Application infact was switching to external gpu and thus causing the system to hung[Maverik] or now reboot in Yosemite.

But now atleast its not anymore doing this, once I have disabled the 2nd GPU. So atleast, now I can use its internal card completely and its not a $3500/- paperweight.

Also we do not need gfxcardstatus app once we disable the external card.

Best of luck guys.

sandocan

Comment: so, what's your current OS X is? and does with method from asyncro dot com the problem on your MacBook Pro has been fixed? Right now I got the same problem and I was downgrade from OS X Yosemite to OS X Mountain Lion….

Comment: On El Capitan, you also need to disable the System Integrity Protection before moving the AMD drivers. See details here: http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295805/251859

Answer (score 3):

I got into single user mode without much trickery, as my AMD card seems to work up to the point where the drivers are loaded, just with stripes across the screen. So I got to remove the drivers as described at asyncro. I rebuilt the kextcache (alternatively deleted it), but my Mac doesn't boot to internal graphics but uses the discrete graphics (according to gfxcardstatus), just totally slow and with what looks like 32 colors and pinstripes across the screen. As soon as I restore the drivers, it freezes at boot with a grey screen. Not sure what I am missing.

gfxcardstatus 2.3 complains it can't switch to internal graphics because there is an external display connected (not true), 2.2.1 just doesn't work.

I am on Yosemite 10.10.1

I also have FileVault enabled, so I am seeing the broken discrete graphics right from the start when I am prompted for my password, long before any driver from hard dis can be loaded.

Comment: I think it's because of that Yosemite update. I have the same issues after I installed it.