# MacBookPro8,2 early 2011 boots into safe mode but not to recovery mode (even with USB)

Tags: startup, bootable-disk

I have a MacBook Pro early 2011 that will only boot into safe mode, trying anything besides single user results in a crash or hangs with a white screen, can't even boot from an El Capitan USB, current OS is 10.6.8. There is also a pink tinge to the screen and in safe mode there are red vertical lines an inch thick every inch (inch tinted red inch normal.) I have verbose here before a white screen hang.

[image: Link to verbose images]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable discrete graphics card and use only integrated graphics MacBook Pro Early 2011?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128180/how-to-disable-discrete-graphics-card-and-use-only-integrated-graphics-macbook-p). Though the linked question is completely different the reason (broken GPU) and therefore the answer probably is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have a dying/dead discreet GPU, as that's a known problem with your model of MacBook Pro. Booting into safe mode may be doing something to help your GPU (I have an Xserve with a confirmed dying GPU that boots in safe mode but not without it) so it boots properly. I would *highly* recommend getting your MacBook Pro replaced as soon as possible via [the Apple program](https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/). I would suggest you run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and verify that your GPU is dead/dying, but this may not be possible given your current state. Similarly, you can run a GPU stress test program like [Unigine Heaven](https://unigine.com/products/benchmarks/heaven/) and see if your GPU quits.

The only thing I find interesting is your previous shutdown reason: *overheating*. [According to this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126588/are-os-x-shutdown-cause-and-sleep-cause-numbers-listed-explained-anywhere), shutdown code -3 is temperature based. That's strange, but not impossible.

In any case, seeing if you can get your computer replaced probably isn't a bad idea since it's pretty likely your GPU is dying. Go to an Apple store, explain the issue, and they'll probably give you a new computer.